# Get the content pdf from ElementHandle.click() - puppteer

Tags: meteor, puppeteer

This nodejs code opens the links in a new tab, closes the link and opens the next one.
I need to scrape the data in those pdf files in these links. Please help

- Nodejs 14.21.3
- Meteor 2.10.0
- puppeteer ^19.6.3
- puppeteer-extra ^3.2.3

```js
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, executablePath: executablePath()})
let page    = await browser.newPage()    
//...
const elemHandles = await page.$$("a[target='pdfwindow']");
console.log('count of elements: ', elemHandles.length) // 7
    
    for (const element of elemHandles) {
      console.log('element: ', element) //element:  ElementHandle {}
      let newPage = await element.click()

      console.log('new page: ', newPage) // undefined
      
      //how can I grab the page after the element.click() above?
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with the current code, exactly? Which site, please? Thanks.

Comment: element.click() returns Promis<void>. how can I get the pdf that the link shows in the browser?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the site. Does the link have a URL? If so, then once you have the URL it's the same as downloading any PDF file with Node, I'd imagine. Other sites don't have a link, but clicking the element triggers a download initiated by JS.

Comment: I was able to get the URL for the pdf and able to open it. But parsing it for data collection is becoming a challenge. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75526529/4451143